# Как передать не стандартный заголовок в curl

Tags: php, curl

Друзья, мне необходимо передать не стандартный заголовок "Captcha" через curl перепробывал несколько вариантов, ничего не вышло. Как правильно передавать такие заголовки?

UPD 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$headers = array( 
        "Captcha: 12ass3");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "****");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('licensePlate' => $licensePlate, 'sts' => $sts)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cookie.txt");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $response;
    print_r($info['request_header']);
```

> Ответ: {"code":1,"message":"Необходимо ввести капчу"}

Содержимое отправленного:

```
POST /***/GetByLicensePlate HTTP/1.1
Host: ***.***.ru
Accept: */*
Cookie: ARRAffinity=***
Captcha: 12ass3
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Заголовок всё же отправляются, но сайт его не видит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Captcha: myCaptchaData',
]);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: так он не видит даже этот заголовок. Я пробовал вот так:  $parser->setHeader('Captcha', $code); заголовок появляется в отправленных, но сайт его не принимает

Comment: @sbaikov, а что "пишет" сайт?

Comment: @Kosmos пишет, что капча не введена) значит заголовок он не принимает почему-то

Comment: @sbaikov Может там case sensitive обработка и требуется передать заголовок "captcha" или "CAPTCHA"?

Comment: @StuxForce я уже думал над этим, скопировал уже из отладчика это поле. результат тот же

Comment: @sbaikov, капча точно передается в виде заголовка, а не доп параметра или в Cookie, например?

Comment: @Kosmos добавил скриншот из отладчка. Поле Captcha в заголовках. В куках данного параметра не нашел

Comment: Тогда, возможно, сервису не нравится ваш UserAgent или Referer ждет определенный, вот и отбивает как потенциального бота.

Comment: @StuxForce в принципе, я все пробовал заголовки передавать, что в отладчике были, всё то же самое